# Allow only admin users to access a resque web interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, resque

In my rails app I am using `devise` for authentication and my model name is `user` for which I have a Boolean field `admin`. In my `routes.rb`, I am trying to limit all users except admins from accessing a url.

```
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
```

. I tried using devise's current_user helper like

```
 mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque" if current_user.admin == true
```

But got the error  `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000000053ac780> (NameError)`
. How to do this? I am new to rails please help

Comment: your routes doesn't know about sessions or logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what worked for me

```
  # routes.rb
  match "/resque" => Resque::Server, :anchor => false, :constraints => lambda { |req|
    req.env['warden'].authenticated? and req.env['warden'].user.is_admin?
  }

  # user.rb
  class MUserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base
    .
    .
    .
    def is_admin?
      # your admin logic here for example:
      self.admin == true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this kind of behavior is to add a `before_action` to your controller which will produce an error if the user is not an admin:

before_action :authorize_admin_only

```
def authorize_admin_only
   raise RoutingError.new('Not found') if !current_user.admin
end
```

Your routes file is interpreted once on startup, and even if you can find ways to make routes depend on the request (e.g. with [`routing_filter`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter)) it is not a good idea to use this for authorization purpose.

In `authorize_admin_only`, you can also render an error file or simply redirect the user to another page, e.g. login.

For your specific case, as you want to mount another engine, you can also define authentication on a `admin` model [in your routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb) (and [special resque example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Protect-Resque-Web-with-Devise))

```
  authenticate :admin_user do #replace admin_user(s) with whatever model your users are stored in.
    mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/jobs"
  end
```

If you don't have an admin model, then you can refer to [the devise documentation for `authenticate`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method) and do something like this :

```
authenticate(:user, &:admin?) do
  mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/jobs"
end
```

(`&:admin?` produce the same result as `lambda{|user| user.admin?}`, remove the `?` if you did not define such alias)

Comment: I am trying to mount resque gem's web interface. So I can't do this

Comment: @TonyVincent I found an example to use devise this way, although you can also use `routing_filter` and define a custom filter :)

Comment: The problem is there is no separate admin_user model , what I have is a user model with a Boolean field 'admin'

Comment: @TonyVincent updated with more precision on what you need

Comment: Thanks for your support @Geoffroy, finally i sorted it out

Answer (score 1):

There is a wiki page just for that in device,

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Protect-Resque-Web-with-Devise

Comment: I came across this page, but from what I understand it shows how to authenticate user before accessing the page , I want to allow only admin users to access the page